# C# - Xamarin : installing android.support.design package

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

i'm trying to install "Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" into Xamarin Visual Studio 2015, but after it starts downloading, this error occurs

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design'
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

i don't understand any of that, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ensure that you have a proper NuGet source defined. You can go to `Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources` to make sure. i.e.: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`
- Secondly you should double check that your NuGet version is the latest. Go to `Tools -> Extensions and Updates` and update if you aren't on the latest version.
- Finally you could also try to manually download the package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/ and setup a local NuGet repository to ensure that works. Chances are one of the first bullets should fix this.

Source: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/842

Comment: non of that makes any sense, the NuGet source is the same, and NuGet can't get updated manually. and on the site, it doesn't make any difference, it just gives me the link that i need to run on the Console, which is why i asked this question in the first place

Comment: NuGet can be updated. See number #2 of my bullets. Ensure you have the latest version "NuGet Package Manager" installed.